# Create model class for XML files with multiple hierarchical levels using JAXB and Java

Tags: java, xml, class, jaxb

I'm working with JAXB and try to create a model class for a XML-File with multiple hierarchical levels.

In my first try I created for every XMLWrapper a seperated modelclass, but I guess theres a way to handle everything in just one class.

Comment: Is this for handling some Lotus Notes output? (just out of curiosity)

Comment: not directly ... but I've stored the documents meta data in xml files :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way is definitely NOT to put everything in just one class,
but instead use several classes:

- a `class NotesDocument`, annotated with `@XmlRootElement(name="notes_document")`
- a `class Item`
- a `class Value` is probably not needed, `String` would be enough

The `NotesDocument` class would contain among other things:

```
private List<Item> items;

@XmlElementWrapper(name="items")
@XmlElement(name="item")
public List<Item> getItems() {
    return items;
}
```

The `Item` class would contain a similar construct for `List<String> values`.

You already figured out correctly how to use `@XmlElementWrapper(name="items")`,
so that you don't need a separate class `Items` for modeling the `<items>` collection.
The same would go for modeling the `<values>` collection.

I think that's enough details for you, I don't want to spoil your learning experience. ;-)

Comment: Thank you! :) Somehow eclipse is not amused when I'm save "value" in a List<String> ... I've created a 3rd class like "Item" and this should do it...